# How to force pm2 to restart after every hour? cli method

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, pm2

I am using PM2 to keep my node.js apps running.

Is there any way to have PM2 restart my app every 1 hour with CLI method?

Comment: Are you working on Windows or Linux?

Comment: https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/restart-strategies/

Comment: @fonzarellagio on Linux ubuntu ec2 instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can schedule a cron restart something like this:

```
npx pm2 restart app.js --cron-restart="0 * * * *"
```

Comment: you can also install the pm2 and then no need to run command with npx

Answer (score 1):

You can schedule a cron restart if task already running:

```
pm2 restart app --cron-restart="0 * * * *"
```

If you start a new one :

```
pm2 start app --cron-restart="0 * * * *"
```